# SAS - Conditional input statement

Tags: input, sas, conditional-statements

I would like to use conditional if...then...else to read in the following data set, to read in using one input statement if source =1  and to read in using another input statement if source = 2. Not sure where my error is. This is what I have so far and the associated error. Not sure if the pointers are needed.

```
DATA results2; 
infile datalines missover;
input @10 source 1. @;
if source = 1 then input @1 id @4 name $ @12 score; 
else if source = 2 then input @1 id @4 score @12 name $; 
DATALINES;  
    11 john  1 77
    11 88    2 james
    22 bobby 1 55
    22 89    2 opey
;;;;
RUN;
```

It is correctly reading in the id but the source is not correctly matched to the id and having an issue with the name and score.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please explain what the issue is. Note that in the post above you've indented the data which means everything is out of alignment which is a problem when you're using @ to specify the location of variables. It reads in properly once you align it to the 1 column first.

Comment: it totally was an issue of indentation. Thank you!